# Comparing three integer variables in one if condition (C)

Tags: c, if-statement, logical-operators

Recently I'm doing a [C programming quiz](https://www.javatpoint.com/c-quiz) to prepare for my final examination which will be held next week. As I go through the questions, there's a question which is quite suspicious that can be found in Quiz 4:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int a=15, b=10,c=5;
   if(a>b>c){
    printf("True");
   }
   else {
    printf("False");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

As I revised on [Operators in C](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators.htm), I can't find a single statement that allows three integers to be compared in one condition of if-else, while loop, etc. The answer should be False and I've [checked it](https://snag.gy/3jpwFc.jpg) using Codeblocks 17.12.

So, my question is: is this type of condition allowed to be used in C? AFAIK, to compare three integers, one should use the logical AND operator (&&) i.e. `if(a>b && b>c)`

Thanks.

Comment: `a>b>c` is valid C, but it doesn't mean what you want it to mean.  You must use the version with the `&&` operator.

Comment: Adding to @JohnBollinger: Specifically, it means `(a > b) > c`, so for the given values, it evaluates `15 > 10` and produces `1`, then evaluates `1 > 5` and produces `0`, so the statement is false as expected.

Comment: @JohnBollinger ah yeah. so I've done what the compiler will assume: (a>b)>c, and it will evaluate to 1>5, which is false. Thanks for the clarification John! :)